# SSAO shader program produces no occlusion

Tags: opengl, c++, glsl, ssao

I'm attempting to implement screen-space ambient occlusion by the method shown [here](https://john-chapman-graphics.blogspot.com/2013/01/ssao-tutorial.html). My SSAO shader program is the one part that isn't working. Here are the outputs of the initial rendering pass, captured in `renderdoc`:

`GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`, diffuse textures without lighting:
[image]

`GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`, surface normals in view space:
[image]

`GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`, depth buffer:
[image]

These are passed to the SSAO shader program, but it only produces white output (no occlusion):
[image]

This is the SSAO shader source.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec2 v_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 v_texcoord;

out vec2 f_texcoord;

void main() {
    f_texcoord = v_texcoord;
    gl_Position = vec4(v_position.xy, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330

#define KERNEL_SIZE 32
#define Z_DELTA_MIN 0.0001f
#define Z_DELTA_MAX 0.005f

in vec2 f_texcoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D ssao_tex;
uniform sampler2D ssao_normal_tex;
uniform sampler2D ssao_depth_tex;
uniform vec3[KERNEL_SIZE] ssao_kernel;
uniform sampler2D ssao_noise_tex;
uniform vec2 ssao_noise_scale;
uniform mat4 ssao_projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 ssao_inverse_projection_matrix;

vec4 get_view_position(vec2 texcoord) {
    // scale-bias texcoords from [0, 1] to [-1, 1] to retrieve NDC x and y
    float x = texcoord.s * 2.0f - 1.0f;
    float y = texcoord.t * 2.0f - 1.0f;

    // pull NDC z out of the depth buffer
    // EDITED: was erroneously scaling z coordinate
    float z = texture(ssao_depth_tex, texcoord).r;

    vec4 ndc_position = vec4(x, y, z, 1.0f);

    // calculate this fragment's position in view space
    vec4 view_position = ssao_inverse_projection_matrix * ndc_position;
    return view_position / view_position.w;
}

void main() {
    vec4 view_position = get_view_position(f_texcoord);
    vec3 view_normal = normalize(texture(ssao_normal_tex, f_texcoord).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0);
    vec3 rotation = normalize(texture(ssao_noise_tex, f_texcoord * ssao_noise_scale).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0);
    vec3 view_tangent = normalize(rotation - view_normal * dot(rotation, view_normal));
    vec3 view_bitangent = cross(view_normal, view_tangent);
    mat3 kernel_matrix = mat3(view_tangent, view_bitangent, view_normal);

    float occlusion = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < KERNEL_SIZE; i++) {
        vec4 view_sample = view_position + 1.0f * vec4(kernel_matrix * ssao_kernel[i], 1.0f);
        vec4 ndc_sample = ssao_projection_matrix * view_sample;
        ndc_sample.xy /= ndc_sample.w;

        // scale-bias back from [-1, 1] to [0, 1]
        vec2 sample_texcoord = ndc_sample.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
        float ndc_depth = texture(ssao_depth_tex, sample_texcoord).r;
        if (abs(view_position.z - ndc_depth) < 1.0f && ndc_depth < view_sample.z) {
            occlusion += 1.0f;
        }
    }

    occlusion /= float(KERNEL_SIZE);
    occlusion = 1.0f - occlusion;
    color = vec4(occlusion, occlusion, occlusion, 1.0f);

    // view-space surface normals
    // color = vec4(view_normal.xyz * 0.5 + 0.5, 1.0f);
    // combined SSAO + model textures
    // color = texture(ssao_tex, f_texcoord) * vec4(occlusion, occlusion, occlusion, 1.0f);
}
```

The kernel and noise are generated like so:

```
std::mt19937 gen;
std::uniform_real_distribution<GLfloat> zero_one_dist(0.0f, 1.0f);
std::uniform_real_distribution<GLfloat> minus_one_one_dist(-1.0f, 1.0f);

/*
 * SSAO sample kernel generation
 */
GLfloat ssao_kernel[3 * KERNEL_SIZE];
for (size_t i = 0; i < KERNEL_SIZE; i++) {
    /*
     * Generate points at random across the surface of a hemisphere on the
     * z-axis with radius r = 1. Initially generate x and y on the range
     * [-1, 1] and z on the range [0, 1], then normalize the vector
     */
    float x = minus_one_one_dist(gen);
    float y = minus_one_one_dist(gen);
    float z = zero_one_dist(gen);
    float mag = sqrtf(x * x + y * y + z * z);

    ssao_kernel[3 * i] = x / mag;
    ssao_kernel[3 * i + 1] = y / mag;
    ssao_kernel[3 * i + 2] = z / mag;

    /*
     * Scatter the points inside the hemisphere using an attenuation
     * function to place more samples closer to the origin
     */
    float scale = (float)i / (float)KERNEL_SIZE;
    scale = LERP(0.1f, 1.0f, scale);
    for (size_t c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        ssao_kernel[3 * i + c] *= scale;
    }
}

/*
 * Random noise generation for kernel rotation
 */
GLfloat ssao_noise[3 * NOISE_SIZE];
for (size_t i = 0; i < NOISE_SIZE; i++) {
    /*
     * Generate a small noise texture used for randomly rotating the sample
     * points about the z-axis
     */
    float x = minus_one_one_dist(gen);
    float y = minus_one_one_dist(gen);
    float z = 0.0;
    float mag = sqrtf(x * x + y * y + z * z);

    ssao_noise[3 * i] = x / mag;
    ssao_noise[3 * i + 1] = y / mag;
    ssao_noise[3 * i + 2] = z / mag;
}

GLuint ssao_noise_tex;
glGenTextures(1, &ssao_noise_tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ssao_noise_tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32F, NOISE_SIZE_1D, NOISE_SIZE_1D, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, ssao_noise);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

GLfloat ssao_noise_scale[2] = { 1920.0f / (GLfloat)NOISE_SIZE_1D,
                                1080.0f / (GLfloat)NOISE_SIZE_1D };
```

The full source code of the program is available [here](https://github.com/cormac-obrien/ao/blob/3df411a89716489e6f4aabe1c26592a51ed9d266/main.cpp).

My assumption is that I'm making an incorrect calculation during the occlusion stage of the fragment shader, but I don't know where that would be. I've checked over the sample calculations and I can't find anything wrong with them. Not quite sure what to do next.

Comment: Why are you scaling the sampled depth buffer value?

`float z = texture(ssao_depth_tex, texcoord).r * 2.0f - 1.0f;`

Comment: @IanYoung that's a mistake, thanks for catching it. Unfortunately the output looks the same, all white screen.

Comment: I think you're creating a w of 1.0f .. 2.0f here: `vec4 view_sample = view_position + 1.0f * vec4(kernel_matrix * ssao_kernel[i], 1.0f);` or is that intended?

Comment: I have to say, your depth buffer looks a bit bright. Check your settings when you create it. It might just be that the SSAO shader simply doesn't have enough variance of data to work properly.